# How can I get the file names and contents of a whole directory?

Tags: python, file, file-io

I have a directory named `main` that contains two files: a text file named `alex.txt` that only has `100` as its contents, and another file named `mark.txt` that has `400`.

I want to create a function that will go into the directory, and take every file name and that file's contents and store them (into a dict?). So the end result would look something like this:

```
({'alex.txt', '100'}, {'mark.txt', '400'})
```

What would be the best way of doing this for large amounts of files?

Comment: are there any sub-directories you need to descend into?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a good job for `os.walk`

```
d = {}
for path,dirs,fnames in os.walk(top):
    for fname in fnames:
        visit = os.path.join(path,fname)
        with open(visit) as f:
             d[visit] = f.read()
```

This solution will also recurse into subdirectories if they are present.

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary looks like the way to go.

You can use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) to get a list of the files in your `directory`. Then, iterate on the files, opening each of them, reading its input and storing them in your dictionary.

If your `main` directory has some subdirectories, you may want to use the `os.walk` function to process them recursively. Stick to `os.listdir` otherwise.

Note that an item of `os.listdir` is relative to `main`. You may want to add the path to `main` before opening the file. In that case, use `os.path.join(path_to_main, f)` where `f` is an item of `os.listdir`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
bar = {}
[bar.update({i: open(i, 'r').read()}) for i in os.listdir('.')]
```

or (via mgilson)

```
bar = dict( (i,open(i).read()) for i in os.listdir('.') )
```

Comment: Why not just `bar = dict( (i,open(i).read()) for i in os.listdir('.') )`?

Comment: Or a similar dict-comprehension:  `bar = {i:open(i).read() for i in os.listdir('.')}`.  The list comprehension for side-effects is considered poor style.  Finally, this isn't just py3k ... I don't see why it wouldn't work on py2k as well.

Comment: I tested it in python 2.7- it is a list comprehension; not a dict comprehension